# Chromium ARM Cross Compilation generating rpm installer

Tags: linux, chromium, beagleboneblack, ninja

I am generating the installer (rpm) for chromium browser to run on beaglebone black after cross compiling using ninja.

**root@2b5071fb9adf:~/chromium/buildhost/src# ninja -C out/arm "chrome/installer/linux:unstable_rpm"

ninja: Entering directory `out/arm'

[15/16] ACTION //chrome/installer/linux:unstable_rpm(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_arm)

FAILED: chromium-browser-unstable-89.0.4339.0-1.armhf.rpm 

python ../../build/gn_run_binary.py installer/rpm/build.sh -a armhf -c unstable -d chromium -o . -t linux -f

Expected permissions on etc to be 755, but they were 777

installer/rpm/build.sh failed with exit code 1

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.**

This  done on a docker container and followed the steps as mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527627/compile-chromium-browser-for-arm-2019

Any directions in resolving the above error while generating the rpm/deb would be of great help.

Comment: The error comes while executing "stage_install_common" function.

Comment: I was able to generate the rpm installer, the problem was with the partition permissions. I am sharing a NTFS partition (dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu) and the mount options are not allowing to generate the rpm. Finally worked, when I tried cross compiling using the partition used for Ubuntu and then generate the rpm installer.